# how can i send methods with props in vue js? i have 2 methods in components but one of them didnt work?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

hi friend i have a question.
i want create todo-list app with Vue an i have 3 components now:
task component is in tasks components is in app components (task is child of tasks and tasks in child of app)

i want handle delete this tasks and set reminder this tasks
i have a tasks array with some object in it  that is pass from app.vue to tasks component
i have a property of reminder in objects of tasks that is have a boolean

---

i want delete task with handleDelete but this function has an error
but
when i write this function in app component it work!
and set reminder in tasks worked!

why  handleDelete  didn't work in tasks component but setReminder worked in it?

my app components:

```
        <template>
      <div class="container">
        <Header title="write your task" />
        <Tasks :tasks="tasks" />
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import Header from "./components/Header";
    import Tasks from "./components/Tasks";
    export default {
      name: "App",
      components: {
        Header,
        Tasks,
      },
      data() {
        return {
          tasks: [],
        };
      },
      methods: {
       
      },
      created() {
        this.tasks = [
          {
            id: 1,
            text: "do project",
            day: "march 3rd at 1pm",
            reminder: true,
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            text: "rest",
            day: "march 3rd at 1pm",
            reminder: false,
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            text: "sleep",
            day: "march 3rd at 1pm",
            reminder: true,
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            text: "running",
            day: "march 3rd at 1pm",
            reminder: true,
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            text: "do homework",
            day: "march 3rd at 1pm",
            reminder: true,
          },
          {
            id: 6,
            text: "go home",
            day: "january 3rd at 1pm",
            reminder: false,
          },
        ];
      },
    };
    </script>
```

my tasks component is:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id">
    <Task :task="task" :tasks="tasks" 
    @DeleteTask="handleDeleteTask" 
    @toggle-reminder ="setReminder"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Task from "./Task";

export default {
  name: "Tasks",
  props: {
    tasks: Array,
  },
  components: {
    Task,
  },
  methods: {
 handleDeleteTask(id) {
      console.log(this.tasks);
      this.tasks = this.tasks.filter((i) => i.id !== id);
      console.log(this.tasks);
    },
    setReminder(id) {
      const index = this.tasks.findIndex((task) => task.id === id);
      console.log(this.tasks[index].reminder);
      this.tasks[index].reminder = !this.tasks[index].reminder;
      console.log(this.tasks[index].reminder);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

an task component is :

```
<template>
  <div
    :class="[task.reminder ? 'reminder' : '', 'task']"
    @dblclick="$emit('toggle-reminder' , task.id)"
  >
    <h3>
      {{ task.text }}
      <i class="fas fa-times" @click="this.$emit('DeleteTask', id);"></i>
    </h3>
    <p>{{ task.day }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Task",
  props: {
    task: Object,
    tasks: Array,
  },


};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### task.id

here you are passing id directly tho it should be **task.id**

```
//From
<i class="fas fa-times" @click="this.$emit('DeleteTask', id);"></i>
//To
<i class="fas fa-times" @click="this.$emit('DeleteTask', task.id);"></i>
```

#### no prop mutation

you shouldnt change prop values , any variable passed by prop shouldnt be modified , its an image of the original variable in the parent compopent , you should set up new emits in you `tasks.vue -> app.vue` the same way you did with `task.vue -> tasks.vue`

check this working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-pasteur-xjgou?file=/src/components/Task.vue)

#### naming convention

the browser will get confused about @DeleteTask (event  listener in you tasks component ) and wont link it to the event since its the sae as @deletetask for him

you already named the other one in **kebab-case** thats why its working

change
`@click="this.$emit('DeleteTask', id);"` 
To `@click="this.$emit('delete-task', id);"`
and
`@DeleteTask` 
To `@delete-task;`

> Naming conventions from the Vue docs say to always name events with
> kebab-case. The reason for this is that when Vue compiles its HTML,
> HTML does not differentiate between upper or lowercase letters

Comment: check the link , i explained every possible issue